# With randomized encryption, ciphertexts must be slightly longer than plaintexts in order to allow for more than one possible ciphertext per plaintext

Tags: encryption

Can anyone give me a simple example of this?

> "For example, if there are $2^{64}$ possible cipher texts per plain text,
>   cipher texts must be at least 64 bits longer than plain texts"

This is what book said but I don't really get this.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it in the other direction; there are $2^{64}$ ciphertexts which will all decrypt to the same plaintext, and this holds for every plaintext.  There are a total of $2^n$ plaintexts of length $n$; hence, there must be $2^{64} \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+64}$ distinct ciphertexts which all decrypt to plaintexts of length $n$.  If we assume that all those ciphertexts are the same length, they must be at least $n+64$ bits long (because there aren't enough ciphertexts of shorter length).

Of course, if we don't require all the ciphertext lengths to be the same length, then it is possible that some of the ciphertexts may be shorter than $n+64$ bits (but only at the cost of having other ciphertexts be more than 64 bits longer than the corresponding plaintext).

Comment: thank you very much sir!!!!!!!
i wish you have wonderful day!!! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Since OP asked for an example of this, let's look at ElGamal. Fix a group $\mathbb{G}$, and a generator $g$. Assume also that the elements of $\mathbb{G}$ are $\lambda$-bit long. $\mathbb{G}$ contains roughly (and at least) $2^\lambda$ elements.

An ElGamal encryption of $M \in \mathbb{G}$ is $(g^r, h^r \cdot M)$, where $h = g^s$ is the public-key of ElGamal. Hence, you can easily observe the following:

- the scheme allows to encrypt arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{G}$ (hence $\lambda$-bit long elements)
- For a given $M \in \mathbb{G}$, there are exactly as many possible ciphertexts as there are elements of $\mathbb{G}$, corresponding to all possible choices of the first $g^r$ of the ciphertext - hence, there are roughly $2^\lambda$ ciphertexts for each message $M$
- A ciphertext is $\lambda$-bit longer than the plaintext.

Note that in the above example, $M$ is limited to being a single group element, but the scheme can be easily modified to handle arbitrarily large vectors of group elements, so that there are still about $2^\lambda$ possible encryption for any given vector of group elements, and a ciphertext is still $\lambda$-bit longer than a vector: the public key is a vector $(h_1, \cdots, h_n)$ of group elements, and an encryption of $(M_1, \cdots, M_n)$ is given by

$(g^r, h_1^r\cdot M_1, \cdots, h_n^r\cdot M_n).$

The security of the above variant is the same as before (namely, indistinguishability against chosen-plaintext attacks reduces to the DDH assumption).